# Resetting Xfce Panels to default settings?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

How do I reset my Xfce panels to the default settings that Xubuntu uses?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

XFCE stores it's configuration for the running session in `xfconfd`. Feel free to back up the files you're going to delete first.

1. Shut down the panel first, `xfce4-panel --quit`
2. Kill the xfce4 configuration daemon, `pkill xfconfd`
3. First delete settings for the panel, `rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel`
4. Clear out the settings for xfconfd, `rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`
5. Restart the panel, run `xfce4-panel`. This will respawn `xfconfd` automatically. Note if you need or want to restart xfconfd manually know that on my installation it was in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd` which was outside of `$PATH`.

This clears it for the running session, regenerates the files, and sets up the default for future sessions.

### Want it in one line?

```
xfce4-panel --quit ; pkill xfconfd ; rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml ; xfce4-panel;
```

Comment: I suggest using the `mv` command or at least suggesting to copy the folder elsewhere before deleting anything.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that. This is a simple reset to defaults. In no paradigm does a **Reset to Defaults → Apply** provide for an **Undo**. I take it the users understand this, as I could not think of anything that would lead them to expect anything else.

Comment: except that using `rm -rf` can be dangerous if you miss-type, If you accidentally move something else, you can simply move it back.

Comment: THANK YOU! my panel disappeared and I was having trouble finding a way to restore it with my old (backed up) settings without logging out, this worked!

Comment: @weronika if it works for you, vote it up.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I did back when I made that comment - apparently it got some downvotes as well.

Comment: Regarding the permanence of `rm`: Non-power users should be encouraged to use the `trash-cli` package programs to send things to the trashcan, which can then be recovered or deleted forever later. After installing (`sudo apt-get install trash-cli`), you can simply call `trash files-or-dir-to-send-to-trashcan` and then go to the Trash later to restore it if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! I have used this to store two separate xfce4-panel configs and swapping them when changing monitor configuration. I did not know about `xfconfd` bit so that was a huge help.

Comment: it worked, thanks except the `pkill xfconfd` it required `sudo`

Comment: @Faizan than your conf is totally borked.

Comment: Similar with https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1658467&sid=bcc75e1a0a469703b5f0b5a12d2c5b76#p1658467

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I can say that would make it easier to just run:

```
rm -r ~/.config/xfce4
```

Then simply log out and back in. This will just reset `xfce4` back to default. I'd recommend avoiding the `-f` flag unless necessary especially if you are using the `sudo` command which is not an issue here but anyway. Using only the minimal force necessary is always a good idea.

This also limits the commands a user has to enter, you can also open up your file manager and select view hidden files and go into the .config folder and right click and delete the `xfce4` folder and then log out and back in. No commands necessary.

Comment: You could just as easily do it in one line, `pkill xfconfd; rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml; xfec4-panel`, which would stop you from having to logout, and not nuke other potentially useful settings in `~/.config/xfce4`.

Comment: The other answer did not work for me on xfce 4.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but this answer worked great. Just thought I would give a heads up for anyone reading this.

Comment: solution from @EvanCarroll is better. Worked for me. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: I found that not killing xfconfd but doing `rm` alone resulted sometimes in corrupted settings.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I didn't want to switch the entire panel to the default, I just wanted to switch to the default layout because I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and there were [some changes to the panel plugins](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/18.04/release-notes#panel_plugins).

Here's what I did:

1. Right-click anywhere on the panel (except for one of the open window buttons) > *Panel* > *Panel Preferences*
2. Click *Backup and restore*
3. (Optional) Click the *Save Configuration* button to save your current configuration
4. In the list of configurations, select the one corresponding to your version of Xubuntu. For example, I'm using Xubuntu 18.04, so I selected *Xubuntu Bionic*.
5. Click *Apply Configuration*

Answer (score 3):

xfce ships with xfconf-query - a powerful commandline utility for dealing with the xml config files inside of:

```
$HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/
```

.

There is no man page (on Fedora only?) but there is help available:

```
$ xfconf-query -h
Usage:
  xfconf-query [OPTION…] - Xfconf commandline utility

Help Options:
  -h, --help            Show help options

Application Options:
  -V, --version         Version information
  -c, --channel         The channel to query/modify
  -p, --property        The property to query/modify
  -s, --set             The new value to set for the property
  -l, --list            List properties (or channels if -c is not specified)
  -v, --verbose         Verbose output
  -n, --create          Create a new property if it does not already exist
  -t, --type            Specify the property value type
  -r, --reset           Reset property
  -R, --recursive       Recursive (use with -r)
  -a, --force-array     Force array even if only one element
  -T, --toggle          Invert an existing boolean property
  -m, --monitor         Monitor a channel for property changes
```

To list the available channels you can open xfce4-settings-editor which is the gui tool for working with xfconf.
Or you can run xfconf-query -l.

We can use this knowledge to create a script to reset every existing xfconf property to its default via --reset or -r

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read channel
do
    for property in $(xfconf-query -l -c $channel)
    do
        xfconf-query -c $channel -r -p $property
    done
done < channels.txt
```

...

```
$ cat channels.txt
displays
ristretto
thunar
xfce4-desktop
xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts
xfce4-notifyd
xfce4-panel
xfce4-power-manager
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings-editor
xfce4-settings-manager
xfwm4
xsettings
```

or slightly better (without the need for a static channel list):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for channel in $(xfconf-query -l | grep -v ':' | tr -d "[:blank:]")
do
    for property in $(xfconf-query -l -c $channel)
    do
        xfconf-query -c $channel -r -p $property
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The defaults for the panel is stored in `/etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml`. So to restore that default, just do:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
```