# Broken panel icons in Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu

After upgrading my Xubuntu to 12.10, the panel icons are visually broken (but functional), see screenshot. Some of the buttons are displayed as a purple gradient. Exactly which buttons are drawn this way varies as the mouse is moved over them, and usually the button under the mouse pointer is drawn correctly. Any ideas about what is causing this?

[image: Screenshot of broken panel button icons.]

`lspci` says `NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 295] (rev a1)`

Comment: What video card are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to reload XFCE.

XFCE stores it's configuration for the running session in `xfconfd`. Feel free to back up the files you're going to delete first.

1. Shut down the panel first, `xfce4-panel --quit`
2. Kill the xfce4 configuration daemon, `pkill xfconfd`
3. First delete settings for the panel, `rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel`
4. Clear out the settings for `xfconfd`, `rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`
5. Restart the panel, run `xfce4-panel`. This will respawn `xfconfd` automatically. Note if you need or want to restart xfconfd manually know that on my installation it was in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd` which was outside of `$PATH`.

This clears the running session, regenerates the files, and then it sets it default for future sessions.

Hope this helps!

(Based from here: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings))

Comment: Ouch. I was hoping for a answer little less "shotgun-like".