# xubuntu no workspaces

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce, panel

I removed xubuntu top panel by mistake, and then restored it using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings), but now I can't see workspaces, tried to add them from settings, didn't work. I'm  on xubuntu 13.10 64 bit xfce 4.11

Comment: What do you mean by "add them from settings", and what exactly "didn't work". Please be more explicit, and provide a screenshot where possible.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by Xfce 4.11? Are you running the unreleased 4.12?

Comment: @landroni nothing important, i  forgot that I can add workspace switcher so i opened a bounty thinking that I messed up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can add workspace form, `panel > panel preference > items >` then click the add button, from there you can search `workspace switcher`.

When I mess up my default settings, I usually add everything like this.