# Xfce top panel indicator problem

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, xfce, desktop-environments, xfce-panel

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

The output of `xfce4-about`  is

> xfce4-about-Message: No vendor information found in
>   "/usr/share/xfce4/vendorinfo

However I believe I'm using 4.12 but...

[image]

Anyway, Everything was working fine, until I had  an issue, and had to do `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

Just to be sure that I'm using the latest version that comes with 14.04, and not the official version that comes with 13.10, I upgraded it

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

All is fine till today, the top panel is a mess, too many indicators

[image]

I can't remove the bluetooth indicator on the left. I can't move any indicator, if I remove any indicator from the panel, the whole panel will be gone.

I tried [resetting xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings) but does not seem to fix it.

The output of `xfce4-panel` is

```
xfce4-panel                                                           
init: indicator-messages main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-datetime main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-sound main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-messages main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-datetime main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-messages respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-application respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-sound main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-datetime respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-sound respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth respawning too fast, stopped
```

Comment: I don't know what the hell was wrong with the indicator plugin, I stopped using it and used other plugins, some from xfce4-goodies, others from elsewhere. I can't really call it a fix, I didn't fix anything. but I'm fine without it. If you know how to fix the plugin, I'll accept your answer, if not, it's fine with me, I'm doing okay, after having spent 2 hours looking for alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12 doesn't seem to contain any packages for Ubuntu 14.04 yet (see https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12), so I'm unsure whether you managed to actually upgrade xfce to the latest version? What does xfce4-about return after the dist-upgrade? If not, maybe using the 4.12 package that are meant for older Ubuntu distro's doesn't work as intended?

Comment: weird, what xfce version xubuntu 14.10 use?

Comment: On my system (with the default xfce4 that ships with ubuntu), xfce4-about reports xfce 4.10 as it also mentioned here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xfce4.

Comment: @Fischer Although xfce4-about might not be the best source for the xfce4 version. This is the output of xfce4-about --version: xfce4-about 4.11.1 (Xfce 4.10). 
Other xfce4 components (e.g. panel, xfwm4) report a similar version.

Comment: thats strange! :)