# xubuntu 14.04 Xfce 4.12

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, xfce

Is there a way to install xfce4.12 in xubuntu 14.04?

I tried the ppa from xubuntu-dev, but it's only available for 12.04, 12.10 and 13.10

Greets
Jens

//Edit
Any news about it?

Comment: hmm. doesn't work for me neither. I used to have 4.12 installe don 13.10. not sure if there's a difference or not. So, how to get 4.12 on 14.04?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

that's how I installed it on my system, but you're right and we're discussing the issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447637/xfce-top-panel-indicator-problem)

Comment: Aren't those ppas for prior versions of ubuntu?

Comment: @tutuca see the question I linked to in my answer