# Xubuntu 14.04: Missing Settings Apps in Whisker Menu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, whisker

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 with the Whisker Menu.

When I'm searching a Setting Application (like Gparted, USB Creator...) that app is missing in the main menu. I have to go to Settings Window and run from there.

Could I change this behavior and show all the applications in the main menu? FYI This is a fresh install in 2 computers.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It may be more appropriate to file this as an upstream bug for the package.  To the best of my knowledge there is no setting to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1320251 Thanks Stephen for the support :)

Comment: Hi! It was fixed in the last updates (Xubuntu 14.04). You have to reset XFCE with these steps: http://askubuntu.com/a/224037/6776 Cheers!