# Xubuntu panel filling screen!

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

I was messing around with the panel settings on xubuntu and I accidentally pushed it to the largest size and number of rows. My resolution is 1366x786 and so it filled my screen, trapping my windows behind it. I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and this persists when I log in. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some information at [Resetting Xfce Panels to default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings) that will guide you through resetting the panel back to default

Comment: No, I don't think you understand; the panel is filling the screen, and windows can't appear below it. Therefore, I have no way of accessing the terminal as you suggest(that I know of).

Comment: You should be able to press alt+f1 to enter a tty window to enter the required commands.  You can then use alt+f7 to return to the graphic interface, although a restart may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Select the xfce-panels window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> to fullscreen the window. Then you can do the rest.