# How to get the 'normal' Xubuntu/Xfce panel indicator?

Tags: unity, xubuntu, indicator, xfce, xfce-panel

I have used [the method linked here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative) to replace Unity with Xubuntu/Xfce and all went perfectly.

The only problem is the way the indicator plugin looks in the Xfce panel.

It is this version:

[image]

But it has some features from Unity, like the Menus from certain applications (VLC, Firefox etc) are displayed within the panel indicator and are not present in the application's window; also, the items from the indicator are in a bit chaotic order, also some tray icons are present in the "indicator" plugin, while others are in the other panel plugin "notification area".

[image]

After un-installing and then re-installing `xfce4-indicator-plugin` is also crushing  very often now.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings) to reset the XFCE panel settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following indications from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/display-network-icon-ubuntu-xfce-panel/):

- Right-click on Xfce panel and navigate to “Panel -> Panel Preferences …. Under Items tab,  put “Indicator Plugin” **right after** the “Notification Area” plugin to improve consistency.
- Tick the box after “Application Menus (Global Menu)” to hide the menus of VLC, Firefox etc (and let them appear normally in their application's window). Hiding session management might be also a good idea.
- To change the order of the indicator plugin items, use the up-down arrows

[image]

---

Before or instead of that one may consider reseting the Xfce panel as indicated in a comment to the question -  the indicated link is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/224037/47206).