# missing icons in Whisker Menu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and recently I find some icons missing in `Whisker Menu`. `Terminal Emulator` used to be in `Accessories` but it's gone. I can still see `Terminal Emulator` in `Applications > Accessories` if I right-click on desktop. And there are less icons than it used to be in `Favorites` in `Whiker Menu`. I've tried resetting `xfce4` according answers in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings/224037) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just find what causes this problem. This is due to I added `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=xfce` in `~/.profile`. I added that line to let Qt5 porgram to use native gtk file dialog but it causes this unintended problem.