# How to factory reset panel?

Tags: wireless

I was messing around trying to get the WiFi ON, now my panel is all messed up and I don't know how to reset it.

[image]

Comment: is it ubuntu desktop?

Comment: no it a  xubuntu lenovo laptop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting Xfce Panels to default settings?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings)

Comment: After system is on do not login to desktop 
Open tersminal and run the following commands then relogin 

`rm -r ~/.config/xfce4`

Comment: i try that commands but not happen and it a laptop

Answer (score 2):

After system is on do not login to desktop just press `Ctrl+Atl+F2` then run the following commands after login in terminal

> cd ~/.config
>
> rm -rf xfce4

after deleting press `Ctrl+Alt+F7` try to login in GUI now should be able to default panel .