# Black Rectangle on my screen

Tags: 16.04, tightvncserver

I have just installed TightVNC server on my hosted Ubuntu using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I can't see my xfce4 menu usually on the top left of the screen where there is red arrow as attached below. The black rectangle is draggable on the screen. Can someone help out?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long struggle, I realized I did not select the "default configuration" when you log in the first time. [image]

I ran this command `rm -r ~/.config/xfce4` and rebooted the box and it worked. More reference material is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings)