# Reset xfce xfconf to default

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

Start by ignoring all of the advice posted here:
[Resetting Xfce Panels to default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings)

Then you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read channel
do
    for property in $(xfconf-query -l -c $channel)
    do
        xfconf-query -c $channel -r -p $property
    done
done < channels.txt
```

...

```
$ cat channels.txt
displays
ristretto
thunar
xfce4-desktop
xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts
xfce4-notifyd
xfce4-panel
xfce4-power-manager
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings-editor
xfce4-settings-manager
xfwm4
xsettings
```

Why is this a question? I don't have Stack Exchange points needed to reply to the actual thread.

Somebody please do the needful.

Comment: My mistake, it says "Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site".

Comment: Ah, yes, that's one of the protected questions. As it says, there's rep points bar just to combat spam or posts that don't follow the rules.  Try to answer couple questions - there's about 5k tagged "bash" and something around 17k questions tagged "command-line", so plenty to choose from.  In the meantime, +1 for effort on this post. Now, since this is basically a duplicate question, we'll mark it at as so. Again, don't worry about it - it's nothing offensive nor something to critique a post. It's just a simple mechanism to cross reference information, so don't take it personally

Comment: +1 from me too here to help so you can write this as an answer there.  I think that this is a good answer and quite helpful.

Comment: Hey @too_few_bars, welcome to [ubuntu.se]. Since this is a Q&A site, all posts here are expected to be either a question or an answer to some question. Please reword your question so that it looks like a question and post the solution as an answer by clicking on "Answer your question". Moreover now you have >10 internet points. So, you can post the answer on that question too. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I worke up on the snark side of the bed.